# Using 'Manager webapps' on tomcat page

Tags: tomcat

How to deploy .war file remotely to server with tomcat6-admin-> 'manager webapps' on tomcat6 default page.

I have .war file on my desktop and it should be placed under /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ on a remote server but I could not understand how to fill the following fields

http://localhost/manager/html

manager webapps:

Deploy
Deploy directory or WAR file located on server
Context Path (required): -----------------------

XML Configuration file URL: ------------------------------------------

WAR or Directory URL:-------------------------------------------------

WAR file to deploy
Select WAR file to upload_____________________________Browse

Comment: How to use this?

Answer (score 0):

The only part of the form you need is:

**WAR File to deploy:** Select WAR file to upload.

Browse, select and upload the WAR file from your desktop. Tomcat will place it into the webapps directory on your server, and automatically deploy it.